# How to get index of first matched element from the list of class object in java (Without using any third party Library)

Tags: java, list, class, collections, indexof

> I have a List of class object (List). I want to get the index of the first user from the list with a particular user status .

```
public enum UserStatus {
    CREATED("CREATED"),
    AVAILABLE("AVAILABLE"),
    CHECKIN("CHECKIN"),
    CHECKOUT("CHECKOUT"),
    ON_TRIP("ONTRIP"),
    UNAVAILABLE("UNAVAILABLE");
 }

  Class Users{
        private Long id;
        private Long userId;        
        private UserStatus userStatus;
        private Date createdAt;
    }

Class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        List<Users> userList = getListofUser(); // this method will give me list of users

        // here I want to find the first user whose status is AVAILABLE

    }
}
```

**I am looking for similar to List indexOf() method**

Comment: Could use a for loop with an if statement where the User's status equals to AVAILABLE?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Java streams and optionals

```
Optional<User>firstMatchingUserOptional = userList.stream.filter(user -> user.getUserStatus().equals(UserStatus.AVAILABLE)).findFirst();

if(firstMatchingUserOptional.isPresent())
    int firstMatchingUserIndex = userList.indexOf(firstMatchingUserOptional.get());
```

Comment: You don't need to iterate through all users then filter and then get first available user. that is unnecessary work.

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate through list and when you find `AVAILABLE` return from the loop.

```
Users getFirstAvailableUser(List<Users> userList ) {

   Iterator<Users> it = userList.iterator();
   while ( it.hasNext() ) {
      Users curr = it.next();
      if ( curr.getUserStatus() == UserStatus.AVAILABLE ) {
         return curr;
      }
   }

   return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
int index = IntStream.range(0, userList.size())
    .filter(ix -> userList.get(ix).getUserStatus() == UserStatus.AVAILABLE)
    .findFirst().orElse(-1);
```

If you don’t want to use the Stream API or suspect the list not to have efficient random access, you can use

```
int index = -1;
for(ListIterator<Users> i = userList.listIterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    if(i.next().getUserStatus() == UserStatus.AVAILABLE) {
        index = i.previousIndex();
        break;
    }
}
```

---

As a side note, the class name should reflect what a single instance of the class represents, i.e. `User` instead of `Users` when one object represents a single user. Further, there is no need to pass the names of the `enum` constants to themselves. They do already know their names.

When you declare the type as

```
public enum UserStatus {
   CREATED,
   AVAILABLE,
   CHECKIN,
   CHECKOUT,
   ON_TRIP,
   UNAVAILABLE
}
```

calling `UserStatus.AVAILABLE.name()` will give you the string `"AVAILABLE"` and calling `UserStatus.valueOf("AVAILABLE")` will return the constant `UserStatus.AVAILABLE`. You don’t need to implement such logic yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you can use for loop ;

something like

```
`for(User tempUser : userList){
 if(tempUser.UserStatus.equals(UserStatusTemp)){
 //do job
 break;
  }
  }`
```